# Undefined variable $router when using example code from lumen documentation

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, lumen

I'm currently trying to build a web api using the lumem framework. I followed [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/) and got to the part where I have to change the routes. The only problem is that the `$router` variable is undefined and therefore my urls are not working (Error 404).

web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('authors',  ['uses' => 'AuthorController@showAllAuthors']);

    $router->get('authors/{id}', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@showOneAuthor']);

    $router->post('authors', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@create']);

    $router->delete('authors/{id}', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@delete']);

    $router->put('authors/{id}', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@update']);
});
```

I tried to change the `$router` variable with `$app` but this makes no sense, because I am using lumen 5.8 and $router was added in lumen 5.4 (I think ?)

Did I do something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Got some code you can share?

Comment: It's exactly the same as the tutorial, but I can post it here too, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

My problem is solved, I don't really know how. The routes started working without me changing anything, but my IDE (PHPStorm) doesn't pick up the $router variable, it's undefined.

In any case, thank you for helping me.

Edit: I wasn't using the right URL. Shame on me

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$router` and `$router->app`

Read more laravel routing here: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () use () {
    return App::version();
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use () {
    Route::get('authors',  ['uses' => 'AuthorController@showAllAuthors']);

    Route::get('authors/{id}', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@showOneAuthor']);

    Route::post('authors', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@create']);

    Route::delete('authors/{id}', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@delete']);

    Route::put('authors/{id}', ['uses' => 'AuthorController@update']);
});
```

Comment: And have you tried using this: `Route::app->version()`? Change it to `App::version()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for helping but the classes ```Route``` and ```App``` are not defined. They are defined in Laravel but not in Lumen. The docmentation you shared is for Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You should like this:

```
$this->app->router->get('/test', function (){
    return 1;
});
```